# Rails giving problems with relational table, SQLite3::SQLException: no such column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, relational-database

Can't seem to find a solution to this one. I have a relational table, BlabsUser, from which I'm trying to find and destroy a record. I'm doing this:

```
BlabsUser.find_by_user_id_and_blab_id(1,29).destroy
```

And getting this lovely error:

```
BlabsUser Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "blabs_users".* FROM "blabs_users" WHERE "blabs_users"."user_id" = 1 AND "blabs_users"."blab_id" = 29 LIMIT 1
Could not log "sql.active_record" event. NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: blabs_users.: DELETE FROM "blabs_users" WHERE "blabs_users"."" = ?
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: blabs_users.: DELETE FROM "blabs_users" WHERE "blabs_users"."" = ?
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:234:in `block in exec_query'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:244:in `block in log'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:239:in `log'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:223:in `exec_query'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:249:in `exec_delete'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:101:in `delete'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `delete'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:351:in `delete_all'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:94:in `destroy'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:119:in `destroy'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:254:in `block in destroy'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:390:in `_run_destroy_callbacks'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:254:in `destroy'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:236:in `block in destroy'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:236:in `destroy'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Why is it looking for a column called blabs_users? Why isn't it just looking for a record in my blabs_users table? Also, more importantly, how do I fix this?

**Edit:**
And I've also tried this with the same problem:

```
BlabsUser.destroy_all(:blab_id => 29, :user_id => 1)
```

**Edit 2, as per request:**
My model is just

```
class BlabsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Migration is just

```
class BlabsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
      create_table :blabs_users, :id => false, :force => true do |t|
          t.integer :user_id
          t.integer :blab_id
          t.timestamps
      end
  end

  def self.down
      drop_table :blabs_users
  end
end
```

Comment: post your migration file and model please

Comment: Does the table have a primary key defined?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Why should I need to? If I'm just finding by blab_id and user_id....

Comment: @varatis Not making any excuses for ActiveRecord, but it relies pretty heavily on primary keys. `destroy()` is documented as _Destroy an object (or multiple objects) that has the given id_ which seems to suggest that it - too - wants an id to use.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Alright I'll try it out in a bit. You might want to post your comment as an answer just so I don't answer my own question :)

Comment: By the model and column names you have, it almost sounds like you are trying to join two other tables (Models)? Have you looked at ActiveRecord Associations, particularly HBTM -- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association

Comment: @micholson Yes, as I said, the table is relational (HBTM). But apparently you can't just destroy relational records all willy-nilly, so I added a primary key to it and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveRecord depends pretty heavily on having a unique key to work with (usually the primary key of the table) Since you explicitly don't have one defined (`:id => false`), I strongly suspect that your problem is related to that.

[`destroy()`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/destroy/class) is also documented as *Destroy an object (or multiple objects) that has the given id* which strongly suggests it needs that unique id to work with.

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit unfortunate that ActiveRecord forces this extra field.